# How can I get all posted data as one single line in php?

Tags: php, post, form-data

I want to capture all posted data in one single line like `name=asd&age=12&city=something` and as an array while the data were posted by using form. (I don't wanna capture values like `"$name=$_POST['name']")`

(Ques-1: as a single line. 
Ques-2: as an array.)

How can I do that ?

-Thanks.

Comment: RESOLVED: Thank you everybody for your helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you want, but I think you're looking for the following:

On a single line:

```
$raw_data = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

in an array

```
$array_data = $_POST // this is already an array?
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes thiss what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

1. `$postAsLine = file_get_contents("php://input");`
2. `$postAsArray = $_POST;`

Answer (score 1):

`echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` for current GET query

`http_build_query` for any array

in your case `http_build_query($_POST)`

Comment: http_build_query($_POST) is helpful. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `http_build_query($yourKeyValArray)` which creates a query string from an array.

Answer (score 0):

it sound like it:

1. `$getAll = serialize($_POST);`
2. `$getAsArray = $_POST;`

GOOD LUCK